# Linearity In Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning linear algebra for few months now and I came to the following notion.

Due to the definition of field:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha(a_i+b_i)=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n}  a_i+\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i$

Due to the definition of vector space if $a,b\in V $ and $\alpha\in F$ then $\alpha(a+b)\in V$, and $T:V\rightarrow U$ is a linear transformation then:

$\alpha T(v_1+v_2)=T(\alpha v_1)+T(\alpha v_2)$

All of the above says that in Linear Algebra all of the linear operations preserve linear combinations? am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Everything you've written is true.

Comment: "*All of the above says that in Linear Algebra all of the linear operations preserve linear combinations?*" Yes, assuming you mean what I think you mean by "preserving" linear combinations.  What else do you expect it to say?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I just wanted to know if all the I have written is correct or am I missing something

Comment: What you have written is correct.  What it is about that which you have written which leads you to believe that something is missing?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that there are further implications that I have not mentioned

Comment: @gbox well, you never explicitly said that for any scalars $\alpha,\beta$ and vectors $v_1,v_2$, we have
$$
T(\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2) = 
\alpha T(v_1) + \beta T(v_2)
$$
and we can extend this to finite sums, stating that for scalars $\alpha_i$ and vectors $v_i$,
$$
T\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i \right) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i T(v_i)
$$
You might consider these to be "further implications", but in a sense they amount precisely to what you've said.

Answer (score 2):

Right...you've hit upon something that your book should have made explicit. I'd have written something like this:

We're looking at fields (like $\mathbb R$) and coordinate vectors over those fields (like $\mathbb R^3$), and when we define transformations, we ask that these transformations preserve field properties. Why? Because structure-preserving maps have proved, over the years, to be ones about which we can say meaningful things. For instance, a little later in the book, we'll talk about "dimension", and we'll show that if $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, then (1) $T(V)$ is a subspace of $W$ (essentially, a vector space that's a subset of $W$), and (2) the dimension of $T(V)$ is no greater than the dimension of $V$. So linear maps preserve-or-reduce dimension. If we look at nonlinear maps, it's quite possible for $T(V)$ to have a dimension greater than that of $V$. We'll see this pattern over and over: linearity --- i.e., preserving the algebraic structure --- is exactly the secret sauce needed to make some statement true. This is just the first instance of many.

Answer (score 1):

This is not just the case in linear Algebra, as a linear operator is by definition an operator that preserves linear combinations. (correct me if I'm missing some field of mathematics, where the term "linear operator" has a different meaning)